# How to override npm dependency that is a ruby gem?

Tags: npm, npm-install, pact, sonatype

I am using `@pact-foundation/pact-core:13.13.9`. Struggling to update few dependency located deep inside the tree. eg: `git` which is a ruby gem.

`Dependency git (1.2.5) located at Module ./node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/standalone/win32-x64-2.0.2/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/find_a_port-1.0.1/Gemfile.lock`

I have setup this project to use Sonatype Nexus IQ scan.
Tried overriding dependency like so inside `package.json`

```
"overrides":{
 "git":"1.13.0"
}
```

Comment: Added a waiver in nexus

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The ruby app installed as part of Pact JS is bundled into the distribution, it's not something npm can manage.

Why do you need to update it?

Comment: It has critical CVSS score.